# Hide Default checkbox inside MultiSelect ListView (UWP)

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a ListView like this

```
                            <ListView  ItemsSource="{x:Bind DDLItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                   SelectionChanged="StudentsList_SelectionChanged" x:Name="StudentsList" SelectionMode="Multiple"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 1"/>
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </ListView>
```

When this Listview Renders on-page, it comes with Default Checkbox inside each item. I want to hide those Checkboxes and show only data. how can I achieve this?

This is how the ListView looks now

[image]

Comment: Set the `SelectionMode` to `Single` or `Extended`

Comment: @Muzib MultiSelection is Required in My business logic :(

Comment: try the `Extended` mode, it allows multi selection

Comment: @Muzib Again your answer is correct, But sadly I need Multiple itself as Extended will behave ina little different way :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hide Default checkbox inside MultiSelect ListView (UWP)

That could be approached easily by edit the  `<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ListViewItemExpanded">`,(in generic.xaml file) you could find the checkbox was made with `MultiSelectSquare` Border, we just add the edit `Normal VisualState` like the following, and the checkbox will be hidden when Multiple SelectionMode.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Normal">
    <Storyboard>
        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectSquare" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

**Usage**

```
<ListView
    Name="TestList"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemExpanded}"
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    Visibility="Visible"
    >
```

Comment: I can't find the generic.xaml to add the code you shared, Can you please share the complete XAML style to achieve this?

Comment: Yep, but it is too long to post above, you could find it by-self, open the MainPage.xaml fine `ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush` then press F12.

Comment: This solution works. Thank you. But there's gap remains even the checkbox is collapsed. I used minus padding-left to fix that.

Answer (score -1):

You can fix it by changing **ListView** to **ListBox**:

```
<ListBox
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind DDLItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}"
    Background="Transparent"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
    SelectionChanged="StudentsList_SelectionChanged"
    x:Name="StudentsList"
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 1"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```