# How to remove system checkboxes from CollectionView in UWP (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, collectionview

I have no idea how to remove the checkbox that is generated automatically when setting the SelectionMode to Multiple in a CollectionView on Windows. I have a custom checkbox, so i don't need the one that is displayed by default. Maybe someone has any idea?

[image: Here is a black default checkbox and my custom check mark]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to remove the checkbox that is generated automatically when setting the SelectionMode to Multiple

I'm afraid you can't remove the check box from CollectionView, Because the matched native control in uwp platform is `GridView` or `ListView` base on the `ItemsLayout` property, you could modify the default style to hide the checkbox for listview or gridview item like this case [replay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747967/hide-default-checkbox-inside-multiselect-listview-uwp/61765403#61765403). Unfortunately, xamarin CollectionView's native control does not use the default system internal style, and the style comes from [WinUI](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/fd3e7fce4467b212df48dd04dee0f49dd4145f3a/dev/Materials/Reveal/RevealBrush_rs2_themeresources.xaml#L1927) lib. That means we can't edit it with style overriding.

For the requirement, we suggest you set SelectionMode as single, and use your custom checkbox to cover the default position.